# Google Sign-in authentication not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-api, firebase-authentication

I have used Stackoverflow and have tried the suggested answers but none of them are working. I am trying to auth a user with firebease and google, my code is working fine. But in this method, I am always getting the toast message authentication failed:

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);

    auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

I believe its something to do with my google-services.json and my google API credentials. I was wondering if someone could please give me some clear steps on how to fix this problem. This is what I did to try make the signin process work.

1. Linked my application with firebase and added the JSON correctly to the project.
2. Added all the build gradle dependencies
3. Allowed Google sign-in from firebase auth tab
4. Went to google API credentials website ([here](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=fir-64408)) and copied and stored it in the strings.xml inside my project
5. Went back to the credentials page and created another Auth token for Android and typed this into terminal to get the ShA1 key:

> keystore -list -vrt -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.

with the password as android

I then entered this key when creating the android Auth token.

I also have all of this code inside my signin class inside the onCreate

```
 GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
    // options specified by gso.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

and all of this too, along with the listener and onstart and stop methods

```
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Passed google login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();

            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        }
    }
}

/*****************************************************************************************************/
/*get an ID token from the GoogleSignInAccount object, exchange it for a Firebase credential,
 *and authenticate with Firebase using the Firebase credential
 */
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);

    auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

I have been stuck on this for a very long time and any help is much appreciated. I am not clear as to what my problem is, I'm only guessing so . If any further info is needed please let me know and I shall update this post.

thanks

Comment: Please limit your post to the relevant parts only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more a collection of recommendations than an answer.

Update your completion listener to log the exception for the failure:

```
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(GoogleSignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

When you run, look at the `logcat` output to see the exception and other log message related to auth processing.

I'm wondering about this step you posted and the order of the steps related to the SHA1 fingerprint for your project:

> Step 4. Went to google API credentials website...

I have auth working in a couple of projects, including the [Auth QuickStart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth), and don't recall needing to use the API credentials website.  The SHA1 key should be entered in the Settings page of your project at the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).  You should do that *before* you download the `google-service.json` file so that it is included in the file.  You can see if the file you are using has the correct fingerprint by looking at the value of `certificate_hash` this section:

```
  "oauth_client": [
    {
      "client_id": "<long ID string here>",
      "client_type": 1,
      "android_info": {
        "package_name": "com.google.firebase.quickstart.auth",
        "certificate_hash": "<your SHA1 fingerprint here>"
      }
    },
```

Comment: Your solution worked , regarding adding the certificate hash with firebase instead of manually doing it on the credentials api page. Thank you so much. Means a lot! I was stuck on this for a very long time